# What is the utility of using TypeScript as a typed language?

Tags: javascript, typescript

What is the utility of using TypeScript as a typed language if it will be transpiled to classic javascript anyway:

so this statment:

```
let decimal: number = 6;
```

will be :

```
var decimal = 6;
```

Comment: What is the utility of using C++ as a high-level language if it will be compiled to machine language anyway?

Answer (score 6):

The utility is in the compilation process: If you define, say, a method to accept a number, and elsewhere you have a method call giving it a string, you'll get an error during compilation pointing out that bug, whereas without TypeScript's types, you'd have to wait and hope to discover that bug in testing.

And indeed, the compiler is just one tool that can make use of this information. Your editor could use it for smart auto-completion, refactoring support, etc.

It's true that the strong typing disappears at runtime, but by that time the type information has done its job; it's a development-time aid, not a runtime feature.

Comment: + easier to write tools: automatic refactorings, code completion etc

Comment: Indeed, good points. The compiler is just one tool using this information, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Because TypeScript allows checking types at compile time, which allow programmers to write, read and debug program easily, specifically if they come from strong typed object-oriented programming languages like Java.

So you can get profit of types -- checking the type of a variable when it gets passed to a function as a parameter, for instance, classes, interfaces and the like.

It's true that, at the end, the code will be transpiled to plain vanilla JavaScript. However, that's true for every high level programming language too, and that's not a reason to write programs in machine code.